# Missing my list field textarea in DispForm

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, list-view, edit-form

I am currently working on a List and I've only 2 Fields (1 Input Text and 1 Textarea (Multi) there as it's for testing something new.

I'm have a function:

```
iseuserlistdisplayer.Findelement = function (internalname, fieldType) {
    var tacol = document.getElementsByTagName(fieldType);
    var idStartChars=internalname + "_";
    for (var i = 0; i < tacol.length; i++) {
        var el=tacol[i];
        if(el.id) {
            if (el.id.indexOf(idStartChars)==0) {
                return el.id;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This function get the id of my field if I provide the internalname and fieldType as parameters.

This is working fine for the NewForm and EditForm... But if I open a record in the Disp Form than I don't have any textarea in my list. 
The markup changes are following:

**NewForm:**

```
<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
    <!-- FieldName="gewählte Benutzer"
         FieldInternalName="BenutzerTxt"
         FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
    <span dir="none">
        <textarea title="gewählte Benutzer" class="ms-long" id="BenutzerTxt_44b9da11-4a9c-45d6-b549-20f65588aa70_$TextField" style="height: 0px; display: none;" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    </span>
</td>
```

**DispForm:**

```
<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
    <!-- FieldName="gewählte Benutzer"
         FieldInternalName="BenutzerTxt"
         FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
    <div dir="">

    </div>
</td>
```

As you can see the textarea is missing and now I'm not able to get the content of it.
Is there a way to keep the textarea in the DispForm? Can I do it in the SharePoint Designer when I edit the DispForm of that List?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe you have to create a separate function for the DispForm.aspx. This form is rendered differently than the other two (NewForm and EditForm).

Just a question though, where will you use the id of the field or what will you do to it?